# How to import specific parts of a nonuniform CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to pull some data in from csv files I have containing physiology data. The CSV file is not exactly uniformly shaped when I open it in excel, which is how I read it. It instead reads to the human eye as multiple different tables. I have included pictures of the file [opened in a text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeTsQ.png) and [opened in excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwWCi.png)

I only really need data out of one of the main tables of the csv file, [the table highlighted here in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc4DD.png) but I am having trouble reading in my file to get the pandas Dataframe right. I have tried by naming the columns in my import to match those given in the file, and adding skip rows arguments, but I think the formatting of the file is just so odd that I am missing something.

I've tried using the basic pandas read_csv command attempting to specify column names and skip rows, but this does not import the table I want..

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('20180801-110239_PTA.csv',  
                  names = ['Saq', 'E', 'Start', 's', '[Chl]',
                           'ADC', 'mrP', 'frP', 'JPII', 'JVPII', 'F', 'Fm', 
                           'Fq/Fm', 'C', 'p', 'RSigma' 'Sigma', 'CSQ', 'TauES',
                           'NPQ', 'NSV'], skiprows=26)
```

The hopeful/expected results include a 12x20 DataFrame of observations with the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have the file, here's my best guess:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('20180801-110239_PTA.csv', 
                  names = ['Saq', 'E', 'Start', 's', '[Chl]',
                           'ADC', 'mrP', 'frP', 'JPII', 'JVPII', 'F', 'Fm', 
                           'Fq/Fm', 'C', 'p', 'RSigma' 'Sigma', 'CSQ', 'TauES',
                           'NPQ', 'NSV'], skiprows=26,
                  usecols=range(1,21), header=None, nrows=12)
```

What the extra parameters mean:

- `usecols=range(1,21)`: your lines start with a comma which it indicates an empty column. This param tells pandas to ignore the first column (index 0) and read columns 1 to 20
- `header=None`:  tell pandas to use the column names you supply in the `names` parameter. The first line in the reading range contains data, not column headers. May also need to adjust `skiprows` to `27`.
- `nrows=12`: read in 12 rows of data only.

Adjust the params as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help I was able to adjust what you'd given me and get my dataframe pulled in ready to do calculations. Much appreciated!